# How to read a csv file and store it in and array of objects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, nestjs

I want to read a CSV file and store it in a variable for future access preferably as an array of objects.
But doing the following

```
const csv = fs
  .createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv.default({ separator: '|' }))
  .on('data', (data) => {
    results.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

only gets me data inside the `on('end')` clause only. Outside it, accessing the variable result gives empty variable and even reassigning to another variable inside on end clause does not seem to work. please review and suggest a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `results` variable to whatever function you need to use,

```
const csv = fs
  .createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv.default({ separator: '|' }))
  .on('data', (data) => {
    results.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    someFunction(results);
  });

function someFunction(data) {
  // do anything with data
}
```

Comment: it does seem to work when i am using a function. however for better readability it would be better if i got the data outside the     function. else all my logic working that data would have to go inside that. Is there anyway I can the get the resultant data to a variable instead of passing to function?

Answer (score 4):

It is because the code outside would execute even before your program is done with reading data. Take a look at the following code:

```
let results = [];
const csv = fs
  .createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv.default({ separator: '|' }))
  .on('data', (data) => {
    results.push(data);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });

console.log(results); <- This line would execute before reading the file. So, results array is empty.
```

You get the data only in `.on('end', ...)` because, the `.on('end')` callback gets executed when you are done with reading the file. So, when the `.on('end)` callback gets executed your `results` array is populated with data. That is why you get data only in `end` callback.

Now, whatever you want to do with your `results` array, you should do it in the `.on('end')` callback.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using jQuery, with the plugin [evanplaice/jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv), to convert a CSV into an array of objects:

```js
var data;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "csv_raaja_file.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
      data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
      generateHtmlTable(data);
    }
});
```